# Múltiplos bancos de dados com múltiplas aplicações

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Fiz uma aplicação com **CodeIgniter** que utiliza apenas uma base de dados.
No entanto, me pediram que eu criasse várias cópias dessa aplicação que também acessará vários bancos de dados diferentes. Ou seja, vou ter dezenas de aplicações e dezenas de bancos de dados diferentes. Se eu fizer alguma alteração em um arquivo **PHP**, logo terei que fazer em todas as aplicações. E se forem centenas de pastas, existe alguma forma de atualizar esse arquivo em todos as aplicações de maneira automática?

Caso contrário terei que atualizar uma a uma o que torna complicado e demorado. O que eu queria mesmo era usar apenas uma aplicação e fazer com que ele busque o banco de dados solicitado. Ter que escrever todo o código usando `$this->db1`, `$this->db2` ... é muito complicado pois a aplicação está feita e existe dezenas de "models"!

Comment: Caro, sua pergunta está bastante ampla e provavelmente alguém votará para fechá-la pela forma que está escrita. O que posso te recomendar é ler sobre versionamento de código, estratégias de deploy e controle de ambiente para sua aplicação.

Comment: Meu caro, eu percebo o que você disse sobre fechar.Sobre a sua recomendação, eu conheço parte do que você disse. O que eu queria era algo relacionado diretamente com Codeigniter. Com PHP puro é muito mais simples e já fiz muitas vezes. O problema é que Codeigniter para mim é um pouco confuso e gostaria de alguém especialista nele me desse alguma dica sobre isso no Codeigniter. Mas agradeço pela recomendação. Todas as dicas que encontrei na internet são muito demoradas de aplicar. Acredito que alguém tenha alguma ideia melhor e esse alguém pode estar aqui no Stackoverflow.  Obrigado amigo. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você vai ter que usar muitas bases de dados, e você não quer duplicar a aplicação apenas por isso. 
No caso você iria fazer isso:

1. www.meusite.com/app1
2. www.meusite.com/app2
3. www.meusite.com/app3
4. www.meusite.com/app4

Tem uma solução interessante no site:
http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/post/10349-codeigniter-conectando-ao-banco-de-dados-automaticamente-de-acordo-com-o-ambiente

Não sei se é adequada pois não sou especialista em Codeigniter.

Já testei e funciona bem.

O que eu faço é saber em qual pasta o usuário entrou para direcionar para a base de dados correta usando as informações do SWITCH.

Espero que ajude!

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**

Não sei se está bom em relação a segurança. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeceria!

Procure o arquivo **"index.php"** que está na raiz do **Codeigniter** e altere as seguintes linhas (faça uma cópia do arquivo original).

Mude "app1, app2, app3, app4" para o nome da pasta que aparece na URL. 
Exemplo: www.meusite.com/minhapasta

```
//Changed constant to my folder -> request_uri
$get_uri =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$get_uri = filter_var($get_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$get_uri = explode('/',$get_uri);

$get_uri = $get_uri[1];

$redirect = $get_uri;

define('ENVIRONMENT', $redirect);

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT')) {
switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'development':
        $db['default']['hostname'] = 'host do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['username'] = 'usuário do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['password'] = 'senha do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['database'] = 'nome do banco de dados';
        break;

    case 'app1':
        $db['default']['hostname'] = 'host do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['username'] = 'usuário do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['password'] = 'senha do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['database'] = 'nome do banco de dados';
        break;

     case 'app2':
        $db['default']['hostname'] = 'host do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['username'] = 'usuário do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['password'] = 'senha do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['database'] = 'nome do banco de dados';
        break; 

      case 'app3':
        $db['default']['hostname'] = 'host do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['username'] = 'usuário do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['password'] = 'senha do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['database'] = 'nome do banco de dados';
        break;  

      case 'app4':
        $db['default']['hostname'] = 'host do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['username'] = 'usuário do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['password'] = 'senha do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['database'] = 'nome do banco de dados';
        break;    


    case 'production':
        $db['default']['hostname'] = 'host do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['username'] = 'usuário do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['password'] = 'senha do banco de dados';
        $db['default']['database'] = 'nome do banco de dados';
        break;

   default:
        exit('Minha mensagem de erro personalizada aqui!!!');
}
```

}

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Era mesmo algo assim que eu estava procurando. Vou testar!!!

Comment: Dessa maneira não precisará fazer cópias de aplicações se estiverem no mesmo domínio. Apenas precisará criar pastas especiais como no caso de armazenar fotos e coisas que pertence a determinado banco de dados. ;)

Comment: Então, o que vi dessa solução (link) é que verifica o ambiente `ENVIRONMENT` que esta para definir o acesso a qual banco e não verifica a pasta em si que se encontra correto? Mas imagino que foi mais a ideia que quis dar, e com isso tem que ajustar a ideia para ler a pasta e fazer a relação com a base desejada.

Comment: Marcelo Diniz, fiz uma atualização. 
Se alguém ver problemas com relação a segurança ou prováveis incompatibilidades com versões futuras, por favor nos avise para melhorarmos o código. Valeu pessoal.